# Python xml parsing - Remove br tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse xml files containing articles published on a journal. See an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
<doc>
<articolo>
<data>Mercoledí 24 Febbraio 2021</data>
<testo>
<p>Row1</p>
<p>Row2</p>
<p>Row3 <br/>Row4<br/>Row5<br/>Row6</p>
<p>Row7</p>
<p>Row8</p>
<p>Row9<br/>Row10 <br/>Row11 <br/>Row12 <br/>Row13</p>
</testo>
</articolo>
</doc></docs>
```

My code is the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file = os.path.join(directory, "myfile.xml")
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for doc in root.findall('doc'):

    for articolo in doc.findall('articolo'):
            data = articolo.find('data').text
            testo = ""
            for x in articolo.find('testo').findall('p'):
                if x.text != None:
                    testo = testo + x.text + "\n"
                    
            print(testo)
```

I would expect the following result:

```
Row1
Row2 Row3 Row4 Row5 Row6
Row7
Row8
Row9 Row10 Row11 Row12 Row13
```

but I get:

```
Row1
Row2
Row3 
Row7
Row8
Row9
```

The main issue is that some part of the sentences (the ones after the < br /> tags are completely missing). Is there a way to remove the < br /> tags?

Thank you
Francesca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `itertext()` (which Jack Fleeting  mentioned in other answer) your code could look

```py
        for x in articolo.find('testo').findall('p'):
            testo = ""
            for child in x.itertext():
                testo += child.strip() + " "
            #testo += "\n"
            print(testo)
```

And if you want all in one string

```py
        testo = ""
        for x in articolo.find('testo').findall('p'):
            for child in x.itertext():
                testo += child.strip() + " "
            testo += "\n"
        print(testo)
```

---

Full working example

```py
text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
<doc>
<articolo>
<data>Mercoledí 24 Febbraio 2021</data>
<testo>
<p>Row1</p>
<p>Row2</p>
<p>Row3 <br/>Row4<br/>Row5<br/>Row6</p>
<p>Row7</p>
<p>Row8</p>
<p>Row9<br/>Row10 <br/>Row11 <br/>Row12 <br/>Row13</p>
</testo>
</articolo>
</doc></docs>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#file = os.path.join(directory, "20210224_SOLE_2.xml")
#tree = ET.parse(file)
#root = tree.getroot()

root = ET.fromstring(text)

for doc in root.findall('doc'):

    for articolo in doc.findall('articolo'):
        data = articolo.find('data').text
        for x in articolo.find('testo').findall('p'):
            testo = ""
            for child in x.itertext():
                testo += child.strip() + " "
            #testo += "\n"
            print(testo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simpler:

```
data = [list(row.itertext()) for row in root.findall('.//testo/p')]
for datum in data:
    print([dat.strip() for dat in datum])
```

Output:

```
['Row1']
['Row2']
['Row3', 'Row4', 'Row5', 'Row6']
['Row7']
['Row8']
['Row9', 'Row10', 'Row11', 'Row12', 'Row13']
```